# Maximum call stack size exceeded when I am modifying words in the webpage through chrome extension's content script

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am building a Chrome Extension that look for a word , and if that word is present on the web page it gets blurred. To achieve this I look for all the text (node type 1) nodes on the web page and replace them with a new node. Problem occurs when I create a new node and assign it the text of the node to be replaced, this script when run gives error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

This problem doesn't occur when I assign a constant string to the node to be created. And this script runs fine.

```
var targetNode=document.body    
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
walk(document.body);
};


var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

function walk(node) 
{
var child, next;

switch ( node.nodeType )  
{
    case 1:  // Element
    case 9:  // Document
    case 11: // Document fragment
        child = node.firstChild;
        while ( child ) 
        {
            next = child.nextSibling;
            walk(child);
            child = next;
        }
        break;

    case 3: // Text node
        handleText(node);
        break;
}
}

function handleText(textNode) 
{

var str = textNode.nodeValue;
if (str == "Manchester"){
//console.log(str);

p=textNode.parentNode;
const modified = document.createElement('span');
modified.id="bblur";
modified.textContent = "Constant";     // this works
modified.style.filter="blur(5px)";
modified.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, false);
modified.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut, false);
p.replaceChild(modified, textNode);
}

//textNode.nodeValue = str;

//textNode.style.filter="blur(5px)";

}


function mouseOver()
{  
this.style.filter="blur(0px)";
}

function mouseOut()
{  
this.style.filter="blur(5px)";
}
```

*This handleText function doesn't work*

```
function handleText(textNode) 
{

var str = textNode.nodeValue;
if (str == "Manchester"){
//console.log(str);

p=textNode.parentNode;
const modified = document.createElement('span');
modified.id="bblur";
modified.textContent = str;   //this doesn't work :/
modified.style.filter="blur(5px)";
    modified.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, false);
    modified.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut, false);
p.replaceChild(modified, textNode);
}


}
```

I don't want new node to be created with a fixed string but i want the text content of old node in the new one. What I can do to avoid this call stack limit reached problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop is caused because you modify DOM from MutationObserver callback. It works with `"Constant"` because you have condition `"if (str == "Manchester")"` which prevents DOM modification and does not trigger MutationObserver callback. Try using constant `"Manchester"` and you will see infinite loop again.
Easiest fix would be to ignore nodes which you already replaced:

```js
function walk(node) 
{
  var child, next;

  switch ( node.nodeType )  
  {
      case 1:  // Element
      case 9:  // Document
      case 11: // Document fragment
          child = node.firstChild;
          while ( child ) 
          {
              next = child.nextSibling;
              if (child.id !== 'bblur') {
                  walk(child);
              }
              child = next;
          }
          break;

      case 3: // Text node
          handleText(node);
          break;
  }
}
```

Also your code will assign same id to all replaced elements. It would be better to use different way to mark new nodes, for example you can use `dataset` attributes.

Comment: Wow! that works! Cannot be more grateful. Thanks. btw can you shed some more light on your other way using dataset attributes might try that as well, what are they where i can read more about them? thanks again!

Comment: Just did a quick google search and came to know about them (attributes), but can't comprehend how this can solve the problem

Comment: It is not related to your original problem but to the problem of duplicated ids. You have this line `modified.id="bblur";`. What you can do instead is to use `modified.dataset.modifiednode = 1;` and then when you need to check            `if (child.dataset.modifiednode != 1) {`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, infinite loop, your modifying the DOM, which triggers the callback, which modifies the DOM etc.

Maybe run the code first. 
Register your listener, 
When the listener fires, remove the listener.
Once changes have been made, register the listener again.

That way your code won’t trigger itself and will only listen to changes when it’s idle.

Think of it like a holding page on an e-commerce website. If your moving the database but still taking orders it’s gonna get messy. So you disable taking new orders whilst your doing the processing and enable them once your done. Same logic here

Comment: Thanks for your analogy! Explained nicely